# How to create "full" AST of a javascript snippet using esprima

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I was following this tutorial: https://sevinf.github.io/blog/2012/09/29/esprima-tutorial/ to create and traverse an AST created from any javascript code. 
I was using console.log(ast) to print the tree in the terminal. Although I have used similar code presented in the above link, my AST looks less informative.
Following is the AST output which I am getting for 6 * 7

```
Program {
  type: 'Program',
  body: [ ExpressionStatement { type: 'ExpressionStatement', expression: [Object] } ],
  sourceType: 'script' }
```

I was expecting it with left and right fields along with variabls (as in the tutorial).
Here is my analsis.js code that I have used:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    esprima = require('esprima');

function analyzeCode(code) {
    var ast = esprima.parse(code);
    console.log(ast);
}

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
    console.log('Usage: analyze.js file.js');
    process.exit(1);
}

var filename = process.argv[2];
console.log('Reading ' + filename);
var code = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');

analyzeCode(code);
//console.log('Done');
```

What changes should I make to get all fields with variables in AST of the js code?

Comment: You *do* get all fields, it's just `console.log` not printing all of them because the tree is *huge*.

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(ast, null, 4))`

Comment: Thanks Bergi. That's what I was looking for.